# Stream binary data (created using FlatBuffers) from Node backend and receive in Android frontend

Tags: java, android, node.js, rest, stream

**Technology Used:**

In the question below, "frontend refers to [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide)" and "backend to [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/)".

**Constraints:**

1. We have rural users in developing market, so the internet may be slow and/or
   jittery/unstable. Due to jitter, we need a solution where we can use whatever (if not all) data is transmitted.
2. We have quite large data (huge list of objects) which we cannot simple transmit through
   [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (via plain REST APIs), as until the whole data is downloaded,
   we get nothing (because we are using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and its onResponse is
   not called).

**Goal:**

1. To convert the list of objects (in backend) to binary data. So that
   when we receive data in the frontend, we are able to access
   serialized data without unpacking. Achieving it through [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/).
2. To transmit this data through streaming when triggered from
   the frontend. I want to stream the data as I want to use (show in UI in
   realtime) whatever data (list of objects) user has received (Even if
   user gets disconnected during transmission). **I am having issues
   here, as I am unable to achieve this through REST API - Retrofit
   combination. Need help here about what to use for trigger based
   streaming.**
3. To reconvert the list of objects in the frontend to Java objects and
   show in user's UI. I am using FlatBuffer here, as it is fast and
   able to use/serialize whatever objects are transmitted. No need for
   entire data transmission to complete.

I am able to successfully implement step 1 & 3 of the goal. But, I am not able to sort out step 2.

Please suggest what is a good and easy way to achieve this (stream binary data from backend to frontend). It would be better, if we can trigger and stream using Retrofit (if possible) in the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Achieved by difference method:

1. On the Node side, use `fs.createReadStream` function for streaming.
2. On the Android side, use `URLConnection`, `BufferedReader`, `InputStreamReader` for consuming stream.

**P.S** - Didn't get any way to do it via Retrofit.